# I am trying to allow the user to take an image and to save it to the photos album

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to allow the user to take an image and to save it to the photos album. I am picking up a few errors with the following code:

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage, self, #selector(PictureViewController.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

here is a link to view the error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhsDj.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

Comment: OMG YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER

Comment: Glad i could help!

Comment: Do you know how to change the name of an app? i currently have a silly name and it needs changing. using xcode7

Comment: Create new question or search via Google